# import javascript files with relative path php

Tags: javascript, php

If I hardcode a javascript module import in my php code, it works:

```
<script type="module">
    import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } "/Root/js/foo.js";
    logFoo1();
    logFoo2();
</script>
```

Not very relevant, but just in case, the foo.js:

```
export function logFoo1() {
  console.log('logged from imported js file1');
}

export function logFoo2() {
  console.log('logged from imported js file2');
}
```

The server path is different so I handle that with a variable `$rootPath = "/Root"` so that my includes work along the project. Like for ecample `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $rootPath . "/includes/headgeneral.php")?>`

How may I add an import with a relative path in my javascript so that there are no hardcoded paths?

I tried:

```
<?php 
    $dir = $rootPath . "/js/foo.js;"; 
    echo "dir is $dir"
?>
<script type="module">
    import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } from <?php $dir ?>
    logFoo1();
    logFoo2();
</script>
```

Althought the string is the same for the pàth, I obtain the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Imports cannot be resolved out of the php code in the .js files themselves as in node.js and so I would like to know if this is possible, and if this is not the way, what would be the way to structure big amounts of js code if it gets big with php.

**Edit:**
This works: `import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } from "<?php echo $rootPath?>/js/foo.js"`
While this does not: `import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } from "<?php echo $rootPath . "/js/foo.js;"?>"`

Throwing an error: net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Seems like the foo script is not found.

Why? Doesnt php resolve then string concatenation and the the built script is run in the client(browser)?

Comment: Double quotes missing? `import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } from "<?php $dir ?>"`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I think you need to echo. as in `"<?php echo $dir ?>"`, The other option is to write to a meta tag and access the meta from js.

Comment: And yes... the `echo` is also missing.

Comment: thanks, I got it working with the `"<?php echo $rootPath?>/js/foo.js"`, however I dont quite understand why this other string does not `import { logFoo1, logFoo2 } from "<?php echo $rootPath."/js/foo.js;"?>"`. See it better in the updated question for readability. Doesnt php resolve then string concatenation and the the built script is run in the client(browser)? Thanks for your comments

Comment: I dont know what you mean by write to a meta tag and access the meta from js @user3532758

Comment: @rustyBucketBay well not only meta tag, you can actually echo php variable into any html element, and then access that element using js, for instance through `document.getElementById('someTextBoxId').value()`; my advise: do some research on ways to access php variable from js...

Comment: sidenote: make php generate the script tag, but _only_ the script tag. Generate `<script type="module" src="...."></script>` and put your JS in its own file. Your JS should really not need to care where PHP is running, it should work just fine living in your webserver's public JS dir.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but I cannot resolve the javascript imports outside php. either the `import` or the `const foo = require('whatever' )` do not work in the client as fas is I checked. My problem is comming just from there, as I need to resolve the js imports from php, I need to path the other files path strings in from the server, this is from php. To Generate `<script type="module" src="...."></script> `and put your JS in its own file, if the js code is in separarated files, I need a way to resolve the dependencies. Hope that makes sense

Comment: thanks for your advice @user3532758. I am new to php and my short wev dev experience has been with node. My problem was solved already at the time you answered so figured out how to pass a variable in. When I edited the question the "new doubt" has turned to be why In the not working case, where I concatenate the path with the php code is not working if the outcome of the both ways I obtain the path string is exactly the same, and part of the reason I was not achieving passing the variable in

Comment: `import` works perfectly fine client-side. The only browser it won't work in is IE11, which is getting killed off by MS next year anyway, but you can run your code through an "es5 converter" and make PHP server _those_ files instead of the normal files when the user agent is IE11 no problem.  I'm literally using 100+ modules in the browser right now, as I write this comment. (`require` of course won't ever work: that's a Node-specific syntax and was Node's solution for using modules way before JS had a formal spec for modules. These days, Node supports `import` just fine. Since v12 in fact)

Comment: You have a misplaced semicolon - inside your string: `. "/js/foo.js;"`

Comment: @TobiasK. thanks a lot for that. I always put the `;` after the imports and never had a problem with that

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the insight. I was not aware of that. I am importing the js files, and see the files and the functions in the sources in chromes dev tool's, However I am not abe to call the funtions. For example for `<button onclick="logFoo1()">HEY</button>` I obtain that the function is not defined. Also in the module import tag itself `<script type="module" src="<?php echo $dir?>"> logFoo1() </script>` , nothing happens. I will make some research to see how can I call the imported code in the client. Thanks for your comments

Comment: That's 1998 levels of JS. Don't use `on...` in HTML, use proper JS and have your script source do things like ```const logFooButton = document.getElementById(`logFooButton`); logFooButton.addEventListener(`click`, () => logFoo1());```, etc. Keep all the JS on the JS side, keep all the HTML on the HTML side. The less you mix, the easier it is to maintain.